# Create Facebook “Like” button on a page without JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, hyperlink

We have the "like page" code on our site now (from facebook dev page), but I've noticed the javascript sdk is slowing page speed of our site (another external request!).

Rather than including the javascript sdk, I'm wondering if it's possible to just have a link attached to a button. On our current "like page" button, when I click it, I get this in the url of the popup:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplugins%2Ferror%2Fconfirm%2Fpage%3Fiframe_referer%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.lifeleap.org%252Fis-my-relationship-right-for-me%252F%26kid_directed_site%3Dfalse%26secure%3Dtrue%26plugin%3Dpage%26return_params%3D%257B%2522app_id%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522channel%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstaticxx.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Fxd_arbiter%252Fr%252Fj-GHT1gpo6-.js%253Fversion%253D43%2523cb%253Df246ad6b1a27112%2526domain%253Dwww.lifeleap.org%2526origin%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.lifeleap.org%25252Ff15a3bdc42a846e%2526relation%253Dparent.parent%2522%252C%2522container_width%2522%253A%2522370%2522%252C%2522hide_cover%2522%253A%2522false%2522%252C%2522href%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Flifeleap%2522%252C%2522locale%2522%253A%2522en_US%2522%252C%2522sdk%2522%253A%2522joey%2522%252C%2522show_facepile%2522%253A%2522false%2522%252C%2522show_posts%2522%253A%2522false%2522%252C%2522width%2522%253A%2522350%2522%252C%2522ret%2522%253A%2522sentry%2522%252C%2522act%2522%253Anull%257D
```

When I paste this url into a browser, it requests a login and then provides the correct facebook page giving a choice to "like" the page. Although it's dirty, it does work.

Been searching everywhere for a guide, explanation, or tutorial for accomplishing this, but have found nothing.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to better implement such a link? Is it a matter of stripping out some of what is there? If I have to use a link like this, I'd at least like to get it as general and short as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Facebook "Like" button that is just a link, not an iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954888/how-to-make-a-facebook-like-button-that-is-just-a-link-not-an-iframe)