# How does Pinterest get my email address without my entering it?

Tags: google-chrome, email, pinterest, privacy, google-account

Which Chrome API or other Google API is Pinterest exploiting here to detect visitor email addresses?

> "Use pinterest.com with Google"

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256083/how-does-the-facebook-like-button-work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954888/how-to-make-a-facebook-like-button-that-is-just-a-link-not-an-iframe

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview suggests the [tag:google-identity] tag for "One tap sign-in".

Comment: So basically if I am seeing this thing with my face it means my ad-blocker, tracking-blocker isn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is Google Identities "[One-tap sign-up](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/)" feature.

> With Google's one tap sign-up and automatic sign-in APIs, new users can sign up to your site with just one tap on a dialog that's inline with your page's content. Returning users are signed in automatically, even when they switch devices or platforms, or after their session expires. - [Google Identity case studies](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/case-studies)

It seems that this is currently a beta API feature which they are currently improving cross-browser functionality.